# Problem when comparing array elements (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary, compare

Hey I have a small problem. So basically I'm passing string to function as an argument, then converting it to array and I'm trying to compare generated array elements with one another and if they are equal it should return ")" else "(", but there is problem when comparing elements and the values are wrong. Maybe someone could help me.

```
function duplicateEncode(word) {
  let splitString = word.split("");
  let newArr = splitString.map((val, index, arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
      if (val === arr[i]) {
        return ')';
      } else {
        return '(';
      }
    }
  });
  return newArr.join('');
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear with the question please?

Comment: Whats wrong with the loop? Lets say we have a string "stack" I pass it to the function as argument when function is initiated the final result should look like "(((((", because every letter is different , but now it returns ")(((("

Comment: And let's say the string is "hello peeps", it returns "((()(((()((" ? In "hello", first "l" is ( but second "l" is ) right?

Comment: You split a string and mapping over elements, the first element will always match and return `)` as the index of the for loop and the map iteration is the same. But it will return `(` for all other iterations as you are always comparing element at index `0` with other indices. So the output of the method will always be `)((((((......`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript's Map object to store if current letter exists or not.

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
 let m = new Map();
        let splitString= word.split("");
 let coded = "";
 splitString.map( s => {
  if(!m[s]){
   m[s] = true
   coded += "("
  } else {
   coded += ")"
  }
 })
 return coded
}
console.log(duplicateEncode("stack"))
```